AzureCommunicationCalling iOS sdk does not have support for Apple Swift version 6.0.2 effective-5.10 (swiftlang-6.0.2.1.2 clang-1600.0.26.4)
I am trying to integrate AzureCommunicationCalling iOS sdk in my react native project. but when i try to import AzureCommunicationCalling in a swift file, build error occurs.
Failed to build module 'AzureCommunicationCalling'; this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.4 (swiftlang-1205.0.26.9 clang-1205.0.19.55)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 6.0.2 effective-5.10 (swiftlang-6.0.2.1.2 clang-1600.0.26.4)'). Please select a toolchain which matches the SDK. 
Is there any workaround for this? I tried to do the following:

Downgrade my Xcode version to 15.1 (I get a different error Failed to build module 'AzureCommunicationCalling' for importation due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug)
Set Build Libraries For Distribution to YES in Build Settings (In this case the error goes away but i get a different error saying Using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported)
Created a new react native project and tried to integrate the sdk. (Same error)

This is my Podfile
def node_require(script)
  # Resolve script with node to allow for hoisting
  require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
    "require.resolve(
      '#{script}',
      {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
    )", __dir__]).strip
end

node_require('react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb')
node_require('react-native-permissions/scripts/setup.rb')

platform :ios, 13.4
prepare_react_native_project!

setup_permissions([
  'LocationAccuracy',
  'LocationAlways',
  'LocationWhenInUse',
  'Notifications',
])

use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

abstract_target 'myProjectCommonPods' do
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  config = use_native_modules!
  
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/..",
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  pod 'AzureCommunicationCalling', '~> 2.13.1'

  target 'myProject Dev' do
    $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
  end

  target 'myProject Live' do
    $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
  end

  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec', :modular_headers => false
  pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'
  pod 'RNReanimated', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated'
  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'
  pod 'react-native-slider', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/slider'
  pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg'
  pod 'react-native-geolocation', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/geolocation'

  target 'myProjectTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  pre_install do |installer|
    Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
    
    installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
      if pod.name.eql?('RNPermissions') || pod.name.start_with?('Permission-')
        def pod.build_type;
        Pod::BuildType.static_library
      end
    end
    if pod.name.start_with?('AzureCommunicationCommon') || pod.name.start_with?('AzureCommunicationCalling')
      def pod.build_type;
      Pod::BuildType.new(:linkage => :dynamic, :packaging => :framework)
    end
  end
  end
end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "$(inherited) arm64"
      if config.name == 'Debug'
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
      end
    end
  end
end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 5.0.0', '< 6.0'
end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtensionLive' do
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 5.0.0', '< 6.0'
end


I am using

Xcode version 16.1
AzureCommunicationCalling iOS sdk version 2.13.1
React native version 0.74.4

I was trying to build react native app on a react iPhone device (iOS version 17.6.1).

Have you updated the SDK in your Podfile: pod 'AzureCommunicationCalling', '>= 2.13.1'

Download and install a Swift toolchain compatible with Swift 5.4 (Xcode 12.5.x or 13.x versions support Swift 5.4).

I am already using AzureCommunicationCalling sdk version 2.13.1.
I installed swift toolchain compatible with Swift 5.9.2 and got the same error.

Clone the SDK repository from the official Azure SDK for iOS. Open the project in the Xcode version or Swift 5.9.2 environment. Build the framework (AzureCommunicationCalling.framework or .xcframework) using Build Libraries for Distribution.

Set BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION = YES in the project’s build settings. Replace the pod dependency in your React Native project with the manually built framework.

I will try to do as you said. Thank you so much for your suggestion suresh.

I can reproduce the issue with detail steps.

Suresh, i did as you suggested. Built AzureCommunicationCalling.framework using BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION = YES (But during build time i got a warning DEFINES_MODULE was set, but no umbrella header could be found to generate the module map) and updated Podfile in my react native project. pod install was successful.  but i wasn't able to import AzureCommunicationCalling in my code. No such module 'AzureCommunicationCalling'

@Fahim Jubayer Refer this git and Azure SDK for iOS

@Sampath Thank you sir. Got my issue fixed by changing the minimum deployment target to 16.0. Thank you so much everyone.

@Fahim Jubayer   Hello Fahim, Good to know, I am updating the same as answer for folks facing similar issue on SO.

As per the github link which shared earlier, You need to change the minimum deployment target to 16.0 to fix your issue.
The issue is due to  with  AzureCommunicationCalling SDK in React Native .
You can resolve this issue by adjusting the minimum deployment target to iOS 16.0 for your project .
To do this, you can change the deployment target as follows:
platform :ios, '16.0'
 

Thank @fahimjubayer-dsi for the git link. Refer to GitHub for Azure SDK for iOS.
After making this change, run  again to update the dependencies and then rebuild your project.
